# How to stop Postfix from accepting mail to root@hostname.localdomain

Tags: postfix

How can I stop Postfix from accepting mail to local-users @ my-FQDN from the outside world?

```
$ hostname -f
hostname.example.com
```

Postfix is accepting mail to any-local-user at my-FQDN. So we'll use `root@hostname.example.com` as the example local user I want to stop receiving mail for from the outside world.

I have a pretty basic Postfix/Dovecot/SASL/LDA setup, but let me share some of the details.

- Receive mail for virtual local domains/users on :25
- Virtual users send mail on :587 authenticated via Dovecot SASL

I've tried reversing users in `/etc/aliases` and Postfix's `virtual_alias_maps.cf`, but no luck. I've run *newaliases* and *postmap* after updating them.

```
#/etc/aliases:
#root: user@example.com

#/etc/postfix/virtual_alias_maps.cf:
root user@example.com
```

I think I have FOUR* (updated) choices left...

1. In postfix/main.cf, mess with `mydestination`. I'm pretty sure I need to keep my FQDN here, so I don't think removing it is a good option. EDIT: Yes, although removing your FQDN from *mydestination* disables the outside world from sending mail to local users, this is not the proper way to disable it because that hoses other things.
2. In postfix/main.cf, is there a setting for `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` to disable this? I can't find one in the [docs](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html).
3. Hope that someone reads this who knows the right way.

Here is the relevant part of **my Postfix main.cf**:

```
myhostname = hostname.example.com
mydomain = example.com
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit
```

Here is the relevant part of **my Postfix master.cf**:

```
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
     reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
     reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
     permit_sasl_authenticated,
     reject
```

P.S. Here is the HowTo I took a lot of my setup from: [VirtualUserFlatFilesPostfix](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/VirtualUserFlatFilesPostfix)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove $myhostname from mydestination and restart postfix

Comment: thanks, I m not the OP but had the same question, and i m sure your answer, even if short, is the best one !

Answer (score 1):

You mention `smtp_recipient_restrictions`, have you actually tried adding the line `check_recipient_access  hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access`?

Place it as the first line before `reject_unknown_recipient_domain,` then in `/etc/postfix/recipient_access`
 add the line:

> root@hostname.example.com REJECT

(don't forget to `postmap /etc/postfix/recipient_access`)

BTW, the postmaster address should always be available, but I have never seen an RFC that said that root had to be available, although I haven't read every single RFC that relates to SMTP.

Comment: I have no doubt that this will work, but there's something else fundamentally wrong with my setup.

Comment: What would that be exactly? You don't want to accept mail @your.fqdn.com ?

Comment: I think the problem is my `smtpd_recipient_restrictions=...,permit` in my main.cf. My understanding of postmaster is that RFC wants it to be available at the localdomain level, not my.fqdn. I could be wrong about that, however. To answer your question, I don't want to receive any mail at my.fqdn.

Comment: Your postmaster address should be available on all domains, as it is the contact for malfunctions/problems, etc. This is one of the RFCs listing the ones that should be available : http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2142.txt

Comment: RFC 822 lists more info, but this should be of more interest to you: `This standard specifies a single, reserved  mailbox  address
     (local-part)  which  is  to  be valid at each site.` the local-part means to the left of the @